# How to continue a while loop in python

Tags: python

I am building a python dice game where two players are supposed to play a vs. The code runs correctly and the first player is able to play his/her round however am having a bit of a problem looping through the while statement so as to make the second player play his/her round. I thought I would add  a `continue` at if statement(at the end of the code )but it says `"continue" can be used only within a loop`
here is my code for the game

```
import random
import array as arr
# enter player details:
player = ["", ""]
player[0] = input("Player one name :")
player[1] = input("Player two name :")
print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
print(player[0], "vs", player[1])
# waiting for user to press enter key
input("Press enter key to continue...")
# clearing screen
# creating an array of 5 dice with integer type
dice = arr.array('i', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
k = 0
busted = 0
round = 1
score = 0
roll = 0
possible_output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print("round : ", round)
while busted == 0 or score < 10000 or round < 6:
    # filling each value of dice array with random number from 1 to 6
    for j in range(0, 5):
        # rolling dice
        dice[j] = random.choice(possible_output)
    break
print(dice)      
roll += 1
# calculating score
# condition when there is a series of 1 through 5
if dice[0] == 1 and dice[1] == 2 and dice[2] == 3 and dice[3] == 4 and dice[4] == 5:
    score = score+1250
# condition when there is a series of 2 through 6
elif dice[0] == 2 and dice[1] == 3 and dice[2] == 4 and dice[3] == 5 and dice[4] == 6:
    score = score+1250
# if value is a 1 or 5;
for j in range(0, 5):
    if dice[j] == 1:
        score = score+100
    elif dice[j] == 5:
        score = score+50
    # printing the results
print("Result of dice rolling is :", dice)
print("Roll total : ", score)
roll_dice = input("[s]ave or [R]oll")
if roll_dice == "s":
    print("saved!")
else:
    if k == 0:
        k = 1
        continue 
    else:
        k = 0
        round = round+1
        if round == 6:
            print("Thankyou, the game is over")
```

Comment: Everything will become much easier when you'll start using functions instead of writing this kind of long spaghetti code.

Comment: You probably need to think over your logic where to use loops. You can use continue in every while and for loop. But your continue is used way later when the first while loop is long over.

Answer (score 0):

Your if block is outside the while block (indentation). You are not executing this if within the while block, hence the error.

Comment: which if block?

Comment: if roll_dice == "s": This is where if block starts. After else, you have continue. It can't be here, you're not inside the loop.

Comment: continue after `k = 1` near the end of the code is not within a loop so has no meaning